# Cannot find .h files after catkin_make clean

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this package i made, that it worked, but I made a catkin_make clean, and then a catkin_make and now the code it's unable to find a .h file that was created from a .srv and it's in the include file of this package.
I don't know what to do. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237774/cannot-find-.h-files-after-catkin_make-clean/) by [thisyearspairo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27253/thisyearspairo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-06-22**:
Please add more information.. `CMakeLists`..etc

Your package was working before you clean `catkin_make`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've managed to solve that thing, but now I have other problems with catkin_make and some packages that used to work just fine and I haven't modified their code, here's come code that appears in my console when i call catkin_make:

```
Scanning dependencies of target costmap_2d_node
```

[ 81%] Building CXX object navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeFiles/costmap_2d_node.dir/src/costmap_2d_node.cpp.o
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp: In constructor ‘RbcarPad::RbcarPad()’:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:264:35: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ was not declared in this scope
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:264:25: error: parse error in template argument list
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:264:96: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertise(std::string&, int)’
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:264:96: note: candidates are:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:34:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:236:15: note: template ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, bool)
Publisher advertise(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, bool latch = false)
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:236:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:264:96: error: template argument 1 is invalid
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:34:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:302:13: note: template ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const VoidConstPtr&, bool)
Publisher advertise(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:302:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:264:96: error: template argument 1 is invalid
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp: In member function ‘void RbcarPad::ControlLoop()’:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:346:2: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ has not been declared
ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped ref_msg;
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:346:40: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ref_msg’
ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped ref_msg;
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:357:5: error: ‘ref_msg’ was not declared in this scope
ref_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/src/rbcar_pad.cpp:385:5: error: ‘ref_msg’ was not declared in this scope
ref_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp: In constructor ‘RbcarJoy::RbcarJoy()’:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:281:35: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ was not declared in this scope
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:281:25: error: parse error in template argument list
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:281:96: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertise(std::string&, int)’
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:281:96: note: candidates are:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:34:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:236:15: note: template ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, bool)
Publisher advertise(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, bool latch = false)
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:236:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:281:96: error: template argument 1 is invalid
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:34:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:302:13: note: template ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const VoidConstPtr&, bool)
Publisher advertise(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:302:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:281:96: error: template argument 1 is invalid
this->vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>(this->cmd_topic_vel, 1);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp: In member function ‘void RbcarJoy::ControlLoop()’:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:363:2: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ has not been declared
ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped ref_msg;
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:363:40: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ref_msg’
ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped ref_msg;
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:374:5: error: ‘ref_msg’ was not declared in this scope
ref_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp:402:5: error: ‘ref_msg’ was not declared in this scope
ref_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
^
make[2]: *** [rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/CMakeFiles/rbcar_pad_node.dir/src/rbcar_pad.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rbcar_common/rbcar_pad/CMakeFiles/rbcar_pad_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
make[2]: *** [rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/CMakeFiles/rbcar_joystick_node.dir/src/rbcar_joystick.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rbcar_sim/rbcar_joystick/CMakeFiles/rbcar_joystick_node.dir/all] Error 2
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:143:3: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ does not name a type
ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped base_vel_msg_;
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:520:23: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ does not name a type
void setCommand(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped &msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:520:61: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
void setCommand(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped &msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:520:61: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:520:39: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
void setCommand(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped &msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:520:62: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘msg’ with no type [-fpermissive]
void setCommand(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped &msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:520:62: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:520:65: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
void setCommand(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped &msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:551:28: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ does not name a type
void commandCallback(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:551:65: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘::’ token
void commandCallback(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:551:65: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘::’ token
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:551:44: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
void commandCallback(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:551:65: error: ‘ConstPtr’ in namespace ‘::’ does not name a type
void commandCallback(const ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp: In constructor ‘RbcarControllerClass::RbcarControllerClass(ros::NodeHandle)’:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:187:1: error: uninitialized reference member ‘RbcarControllerClass::msg’ [-fpermissive]
RbcarControllerClass(ros::NodeHandle h) : diagnostic_(),
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:56: error: ‘ackermann_msgs’ was not declared in this scope
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:46: error: parse error in template argument list
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [8], int, void (RbcarControllerClass::*)(...), RbcarControllerClass* const)’
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: note: candidates are:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:389:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M), T* obj,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:389:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:400:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M) const, T* obj,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:400:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:452:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr&), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:452:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:462:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr&)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:462:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:516:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), const boost::shared_ptr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M),
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:516:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:527:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, const boost::shared_ptr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M) const,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:527:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:581:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr&), const boost::shared_ptr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:581:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:592:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr&)const, const boost::shared_ptr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:592:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:643:14: note: template ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(M), const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*fp)(M), const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:643:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:691:14: note: template ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr&), const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*fp)(const boost::shared_ptr&), const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:691:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:737:14: note: template ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, const boost::function<void (const boost::shared_ptr&)>& callback,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:737:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
from /home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:36:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:786:14: note: template<class M, class C> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(C)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, const boost::function<void (C)>& callback,
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:786:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/claudia/catkin_ws/src/rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp:278:153: error: template argument 1 is invalid
cmd_sub_ = rbcar_robot_control_node_handle.subscribe<ackermann_msgs::AckermannDriveStamped>("command", 1, &RbcarControllerClass::commandCallback, this);
^
make[2]: *** [rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/CMakeFiles/rbcar_robot_control_node.dir/src/rbcar_robot_control.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rbcar_sim/rbcar_robot_control/CMakeFiles/rbcar_robot_control_node.dir/all] Error 2
Linking CXX executable /home/claudia/catkin_ws/devel/lib/costmap_2d/costmap_2d_node
[ 81%] Built target costmap_2d_node
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

And those are not packages I've made, they're downloaded from github, and I didn't change a single thing before the catkin_make clean.

---

Originally posted by [thisyearspairo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27253/thisyearspairo/) with karma: 6 on 2016-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0